# In qualtrics survey question Hide Next Button until HTML-embedded iFrame video is finished playing

Tags: javascript, html, qualtrics

This is the code that I have been trying but it is not working.
I am hoping that when the video ends the "NEXT" button should be displayed and if someone forwards the video to the very end even then the "NEXT" button should appear else it should be hidden.

```html
  <div style="text-align: left;">
    <span style="font-size: 19px;">
      <strong>Play Video</strong> //video is hosted on canvas platform
    </span>
    <br />
    &nbsp;
  </div>

  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <iframe
      id="video-player"
      src="VIDEO-SRC LINK"
      width="560"
      height="320"
    ></iframe>
  </div>
```

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function () {
  this.hideNextButton();
});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function () {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("video-player");
  var that = this;

  iframe.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var videoPlayer = iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector("video");

    videoPlayer.addEventListener("ended", function () {
      that.showNextButton();
    });

    videoPlayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
      if (isVideoNearEnd(videoPlayer)) {
        videoPlayer.pause();
        that.showNextButton();
      }
    });
  });

  function isVideoNearEnd(player) {
    var currentTime = player.currentTime;
    var duration = player.duration;
    var threshold = 1.5; // Adjust this threshold as needed

    return currentTime >= duration - threshold;
  }
});
```